# $wpdb->insert() and Values for Datetime Columns?

Tags: wpdb

I have a custom table with a DATETIME column. I have a function to add records; I would like to add an `$expires` argument to this function which can hold a unix timestamp noting when the record should expire. I would like to use `$wpdb->insert()` to populate this column. So far I've been unable to find a WordPress convenience function to massage the timestamp into 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. Is there such a builtin, or should I just use `$wpdb->prepare()`, or possibly a third option?

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't you just use PHP's `date()` function?

```
$prepared_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $expires );
```

Comment: That should do the formatting job and $wpdb->prepare() is the preferred method to do that in wordpress.

Comment: I'm using that currently (well, `strftime()`) but I thought I was just missing a WordPress-delivered function. Seems like something that would exist, to prevent having the datetime format in multiple places.

Comment: Yeah, they have a function for getting that format for the current time, but not from a specific timestamp: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l44